# getting incorrect values in R paste statement

Tags: mysql, r

I am attempting to write a query statement to put R results into a SQL database.  The results I am trying to write to the data-base look like:

```
print(results)
b1    b17    i8    i9
.03  .04   .77   .01
```

And I use the following to create the query statement:

```
inserts<-sprintf("INSERT INTO `%s` (%s) VALUES (%s);",
"dbname",
paste(sprintf("`%s`",colnames(results)), collapse=", "),
sapply(1:nrow(results), function(i){
paste(sprintf("%s",unlist(results[i,],use.names=FALSE))
,collapse=", ")}))
```

Which yields the following and works correctly when I run it:

```
print(inserts)
[1] "INSERT INTO `dbname` (`b1`, `b17`, `i8`, `i9`) VALUES (.03, .04, .77, .01);"
```

The problem I am having is that I have two other column fields in the database: `grp_num` and `analysis_id` that I also want to include in the query statement.  In the case of the results presented above these look as follows:

```
print(grp_num)
   num
1   28
print(analysis_id)
[1] 118
```

I then cbind these to `results` and get the following:

```
results<-cbind(grp_num,analysis_id,results)
print(results)
 grp_num    analysis_id    b1    b17    i8    i9
    28           118      .03   .04    .77   .01
```

I then run the same code for `inserts` as shown above; however, now I get incorrect values for `b1`, `b17`, `i8`, and `i9` which looks like this:

```
print(inserts)
[1] "INSERT INTO `dbname` (`grp_num`, `analysis_id`, `b1`, `b17`, `i8`, `i9`) VALUES (28, 118, 1, 2, 2, 1);"
```

So I am getting 1s and 2s, which I am not sure what they correspond to, any ideas on how I could fix this?  Thank you.

Comment: Try `results<-cbind(grp_num,analysis_id,results,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: I am still having the issue.

Comment: It's difficult to be more precise because how R _prints_ objects to the console provides almost zero information. So we really have no idea what `grp_num`, `analysis` and `results` actually are. But the root cause of you difficulties here is almost certainly that you are using a sort of random collection of data structures, including one odd choice (matrix?) and expecting something sensible from `cbind()`.

Comment: `grp_num` `analysis_id` and `results` are all data-frames, as I have specified them as such.  However, it looks like R is treating the `b1`, `b17`, `i8`, and `i9`, values as factors instead of just numbers.

Comment: Then I am certain that @nicola is generally correct, your problem is the unwanted coercion to factors at some point. But without a completely reproducible example I'm hesitant to do much more.

Comment: Well whatever I can provide (other than raw data) to make it more useful, I am a bit lost.

Comment: I was able to figure it out based on both of your comments, thank you!